# lucene does not invoke operation until service disconnect

Tags: java, database, elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

I am trying to update the lucene index using `IndexWriter`, using `IndexWriter.deleteDocument()` and `IndexWriter.updateDocument()` however when I commit and close the `Writer`, changes are not reflected when searching the index until I stop the service that is invoking these operations, is there a way to flush/force the changes during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reopen your IndexReader, see [DirectoryReader.openIfChanged](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader.html#openIfChanged-org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader-).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  Even after a new reader is opened using the corresponding writer that made `updateDocument` changes, I still cannot see the new documents when search is performed.